# How to access a file on an iPhone via XCode / Organiser

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This seems like it probably has a really obvious answer, however I am having no luck finding it.

If I write to file on an iPhone (i.e the NSDocumentDirectory folder of that application), is there an easy way to get that file so I can view it via XCode / Organiser / some other method?

I.e, if I create a output log file and want to read it on my mac, what is the easiest way to get to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ then your simulator version and inside that you will find your application (it will be some random name - you will have to search it) .

EDIT
and when you want to do it in a device use this...

[(iphone) access device's documents directory from mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495508/iphone-access-devices-documents-directory-from-mac)

Comment: I'm actually working on a device (and can't run my code on the simulator for several reasons).
Or does the iPhone mirror it's file system into that directory regardless?