# How to record a video with avfoundation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, video-capture

I am trying to figure out how to record a video using AVFoundation in Swift. I have got as far as creating a custom camera but I only figured out how to take still pictures with it and I can't figure out how to record video. From what I understand you have to use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to get the data from the recording but I can't figure out how to start the recording and implement the delegate methods.

The whole AVFoundation Programing Guide/Still and Video Media Capture is in Objective-C and I can't seem to decipher it out. Here's my attempt to accomplish this task:

First I set up the camera/capture session

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in devices {
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    beginSession()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then once beginSession() is called I set up the live feed

```
func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))
    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(takePhotoButton)
    self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(self.snappedPicture)
    self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(self.backButton)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.frame
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

Here's where I get stuck where the user presses record to actually record and capture a video:

```
@IBAction func takeVideoAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self

    var videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    self.captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)

    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "filePath")

    videoFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)

}
```

Then I call `self.videoFileOutput.stopRecording()`.

Then lastly the delegate methods

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    return
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
    return
}
```

And nothing happens as you can imagine because I can't figure out how to implement it correctly.

Comment: Check if the file path is really correct. It must be in an existing directory.

Comment: Is everything else correct though???

Comment: The file directory I am using is valid

Comment: What do you *want* to do inside the delegate methods?

Comment: not quite sure maybe just tell the user when the camera is recording and when it is finished recording, however I can't even figure out how to record and so I've never actually have gotten the delegate methods to get called

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have tried your code. When set a meaningful `filePath`, everything goes fine. Change your `filePath` like this and you will get the delegate methods invoked:

```
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let filePath = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("temp")

    // Do recording and save the output to the `filePath`
    videoFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

Comment: Do you know where I can find the recorded video, I can't locate the directory anywhere on my phone or grab it anywhere using code

Comment: It's under the document directory of your app. You may refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977276/2638425) for locating it.

Comment: So one more question, I'm having trouble playing back the video because the recordingOutputURL doesn't work when I try to play a video by its URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you elaborate it? how do you play it? do you play the video when it has done with recording?

Comment: I tried the code above and my app crashes. do you mind share the working code @jimmy

Comment: i am trying it, but getting delegate error.  Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to specified type 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate?'

Comment: @AkhileshSharma you need to make your 'ViewController' inherit from the 'AVCaptureFileOutoutRecordingDelegate' protocol and implement it's delegate methods