# How do I obtain a .plist saved in Documents, programmatically with Swift or manually from Finder/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

**Background** 
I have a dictionary with more than 100 keys that I've stored in a property list that I can transfer/load/save to from one Xcode project to another.

**Research** 
I've looked at several posts on StackOverflow but most of them seem to deal with loading a plist from the main bundle, copying it to the Documents directory and loading/saving it from there with no way of retrieving it to use in other projects.

**TLDR** 
I want to be able to 'export' a plist created programmatically as a separate file I can use in other projects unrelated to the current one.

**Update** 
Thanks to @NSNoob I've figured out that I can manually access the new plist from the Documents directory. Now the question is, how? Isn't iOS sandboxed without access to the filesystem unless it's jailbroken?

Comment: Is the said plist in your main project bundle?

Comment: @NSNoob yup the empty one is located in the main project bundle which my code copies into the documents directory and modifies it there with no changes to the former one (which is what I /don't/ want happening)

Comment: You cannot modify the original plist. It will remain the same.

Comment: You want to write that plist to your main bundle, that's not possible.

Comment: @NSNoob so there is no way of creating a property list that is exportable in Swift?

Comment: Not in Objective C either. You simply can't write to your main bundle.

Comment: You can export but not in the main bundle, you can write in the Document directory for example.

Comment: @NSNoob ah that's too bad. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: You are still unclear, now you are saying you want to export the plist instead of writing it to your main bundle. Why don't you just access the modified plist in documents directory and do what you want with it? Export it how? Writing to some directory? Sending it to a server?

Comment: @NSNoob I want to be able to obtain the modified .plist as a file that I can use in another Xcode project for example. A sort of output file I guess.

Comment: @cyril You can either manually pick up the saved plist from document directory and then import it in your other Xcode project. A better solution would be to maintain a server where you save the plist and use it between your different projects using Network.

Comment: @NSNoob that makes more sense - now the modified question is, how do I manually access the new plist in the document directory?

Comment: See my answer. Adding screenshots in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Documents directory contents of your app like following:

1. Connect your device to your mac
2. Open your Xcode
3. Click on Window and select Devices

[image]

4. Click on your device
5. Search for your app in installed apps list
6. Click on your app
7. Click on gear icon
8. Click on Download Container.

[image]

9. Right Click on Saved `xcappdata` file.
10. Click on Show package contents.

[image]

That will open your documents directory and you will be able to find your modified plist there.

Comment: Thanks! Also used this to achieve the same result! http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977276/4283749

Comment: @cyril Ah yes that's the same thing