# How to save captured image in to the document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avcapturesession, alassetslibrary

I captured image using below code

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

[session startRunning];

_stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
```

when i press the button

```
   AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
       for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in _stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", _stillImageOutput);
[_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments)
     {
         // Do something with the attachments.
         NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
     }
     else
         NSLog(@"no attachments");

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];



     self.vImage.image = image;
     _vImage.hidden=YES;
     UIStoryboard *storybord=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

     shareViewController   *shareview=[storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"share"];
     [self presentViewController:shareview animated:YES completion:nil];

     shareview.shareimageview.image=image;

     NSMutableArray *temparray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:image,nil];
    NSMutableArray  *newparsetile=[@[@"you"]mutableCopy];
     shareview.newtile=newparsetile;
     shareview.selectedimgarray=temparray;


     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Shareimage" object:image];


 }];
```

how to save the output image in to the device document directory,can any body help me out,answer with code is appreciated,since i am new to the ios objective c,the people who want to customize the camera like instagram can use my code it is 100% working

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_name”]]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Comment: In the button click event after capturing/selecting the image.

Comment: app is getting crashed at NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_name”]]; with out promoting crash message in the log

Comment: Replace with this  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image_name"];

Comment: @"image_name"  what should i add

Comment: It is just a file name. You can give any string.

Comment: Are you testing it in iOS device or simulator?

Comment: device,how can we capture image using stimulator

Comment: We can't capture image in simulator. I am asking about where u have checked that the image is saved or not. If you test it in device, then the image will not store in the mac document directory. It will store in the device app document directory.

Comment: Refer this for downloading the device documents directory from mac.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495508/iphone-access-devices-documents-directory-from-mac

Answer (score 0):

```
// Saving it to documents direcctory
     NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

     NSString *documentDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString* filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.png"];
     NSData *imageData = // Some Image data;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

     if ([imageData writeToURL:url atomically:YES]) {
         NSLog(@"Success");
     }
     else{
         NSLog(@"Error");
     }
```

You can use above code to save an image to documents directory. Instead of imagedata variable you can pass your variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce    but we are redefining these  NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu: Ok , You can simply put the writing code where ever you want to write an image to documents directory as per your need.I am editing the answer if its resolve your problem . Mark it as answer in order to help others.

Comment: it is not getting saved.in tis place what should i give

Comment: If you are getting the NSData of your image then you just need to write using the above code. Instead of "imageData" variable put your variable.

Comment: captured image is not showing in the document directory

Comment: Debug the filepath and try to look at the same path and also check if it goes in to sucess or error . If error check whether your Data is nil or not.

Comment: NSData *imageData = // Some Image data; some image data means 
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];,it is showing error as unexpected use of interface name nsurl expected expression  , use of undeclared identifier url

Comment: No , NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; , It doesn't means that.  ImageData means 
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];